# setting a tablix in front of an image

Tags: dynamics-crm, visual-studio-2019

I am working with Visual Studio 2019, for an SSRS report in Dynamics 365 online.

My problem is with a background image, underneath a tablix.  If I set a background image to a rectangle, and a tablix above it (zindex 0 for both, it's grayed out), this works when the report is exported to PDF, but the particular font does not appear.  The background image of the rectangle does not appear when exported to word, but the particular font does appear.

If I don't use a rectangle, but simply an image, and then a tablix over it, both are again Zindex 0 (grayed out), and the picture shows up in microsoft word, with the particualr font, but the tablix is below the picture, rather than stacked on top.

Is there a solution here?  Either to be able to adjust the Zindex, or to get the tablix to appear above image? My preference would be for both the font and the background image to appear.